# How to center a entity in the window with Bevy?

Tags: rust, transform, bevy

I'm making a 2048 game in rust using bevy to learn about the game engine.

In this moment I'm making the scene with the main menu, but I'm having a problem to work with the `Transform` struct. Maybe is a problem with my understand of how Bevy works.

This is the function responsible of create the main menu.

```
pub fn main_menu(mut commands: Commands, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>) {
        commands
            .spawn(NodeBundle {
                style: Style {
                    size: Size {
                        width: Val::Percent(60.0),
                        height: Val::Percent(60.0),
                    },
                    ..default()
                },
   /* ------> */transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), // <-------
                background_color: Color::rgba_u8(92, 64, 64, 35).into(),
                ..default()
            })
            .with_children(|parent| {
                // text
                parent.spawn(TextBundle {
                    text: Text {
                        sections: vec![TextSection {
                            value: "2048".to_string(),
                            style: TextStyle {
                                font: asset_server
                                    .load("font/Inconsolata-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf"),
                                font_size: 50.0,
                                color: Color::rgba_u8(168, 168, 168, 255).into(),
                            },
                        }],
                        ..Default::default()
                    },
                    ..Default::default()
                });
            });

        println!("Hello from main menu!!");
    }
```

I tried to use the `Global Transform` an the `Transform` structs but there is no difference.

I thought that could be a problem of using relative sizes by using percent, but I changed the size to using pixels instead and didn't work either.

The rectangle is rendered in the top left of the screen all the time.

[Bevy window print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TZRP.png)

Do you know the rigth way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason that I don't understand the transform is not working with elements that don't use a sprite, to solve the situation in this case I use the `Style` component for `Nodes` that follows a `css` approach, I think that is amaizing by the way.

It works to create a simple ui, so I guess that is a victory for now.

This is the result:

```
pub fn main_menu(mut commands: Commands, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>) {
        // Main container for the main_menu interface
        commands
            .spawn(NodeBundle {
                style: Style {
                    size: Size::width(Val::Percent(100.0)),
                    flex_direction: FlexDirection::Column,
                    justify_content: JustifyContent::Center,
                    align_items: AlignItems::Center,
                    ..default()
                },
                ..default()
            })
            .with_children(|parent| {
                parent
                    .spawn(NodeBundle {
                        style: Style {
                            size: Size {
                                width: Val::Percent(60.0),
                                height: Val::Percent(75.0),
                            },
                            flex_direction: FlexDirection::Column,
                            justify_content: JustifyContent::Center,
                            align_items: AlignItems::Center,
                            ..default()
                        },
                        //background_color: Color::rgba_u8(92, 64, 64, 35).into(),
                        ..default()
                    })
                    // Game title
                    .with_children(|parent| {
                        parent.spawn(TextBundle {
                            text: Text {
                                sections: vec![TextSection {
                                    value: "2048".to_string(),
                                    style: TextStyle {
                                        font: asset_server
                                            .load("font/Inconsolata-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf"),
                                        font_size: 75.0,
                                        color: Color::rgba_u8(168, 168, 168, 255).into(),
                                    },
                                }],
                                ..Default::default()
                            },
                            ..Default::default()
                        });
                    })
                    .with_children(|parent| {
                        parent
                            .spawn(ButtonBundle {
                                style: Style {
                                    size: Size::new(Val::Percent(100.0), Val::Px(50.0)),
                                    // horizontally center child text
                                    justify_content: JustifyContent::Center,
                                    // vertically center child text
                                    align_items: AlignItems::Center,
                                    ..default()
                                },
                                ..default()
                            })
                            .with_children(|parent| {
                                parent.spawn(TextBundle::from_section(
                                    "Play!",
                                    TextStyle {
                                        font: asset_server
                                            .load("font/Inconsolata-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf"),
                                        font_size: 30.0,
                                        color: Color::rgba_u8(168, 168, 168, 255).into(),
                                    },
                                ));
                            });
                    })
                    .with_children(|parent| {
                        parent
                            .spawn(ButtonBundle {
                                style: Style {
                                    size: Size::new(Val::Percent(100.0), Val::Px(50.0)),
                                    // horizontally center child text
                                    justify_content: JustifyContent::Center,
                                    // vertically center child text
                                    align_items: AlignItems::Center,
                                    ..default()
                                },
                                ..default()
                            })
                            .with_children(|parent| {
                                parent.spawn(TextBundle::from_section(
                                    "Scores",
                                    TextStyle {
                                        font: asset_server
                                            .load("font/Inconsolata-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf"),
                                        font_size: 30.0,
                                        color: Color::rgba_u8(168, 168, 168, 255).into(),
                                    },
                                ));
                            });
                    })
                    .with_children(|parent| {
                        parent
                            .spawn(ButtonBundle {
                                style: Style {
                                    size: Size::new(Val::Percent(100.0), Val::Px(50.0)),
                                    // horizontally center child text
                                    justify_content: JustifyContent::Center,
                                    // vertically center child text
                                    align_items: AlignItems::Center,
                                    ..default()
                                },
                                ..default()
                            })
                            .with_children(|parent| {
                                parent.spawn(TextBundle::from_section(
                                    "Exit",
                                    TextStyle {
                                        font: asset_server
                                            .load("font/Inconsolata-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf"),
                                        font_size: 30.0,
                                        color: Color::rgba_u8(168, 168, 168, 255).into(),
                                    },
                                ));
                            });
                    });
            });
    }
```

[bevy ui print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHdZO.png)

I actually followed a bevy example to solve this, here you can find it: [bevy ui example](https://bevyengine.org/examples/ui/ui/)